# List operations of a TFLite model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm having trouble trying to list the operations of a TFLite model. I know operations can be listed given a frozen graph, but what about a TFLite `.tflite` model? Can operations be listed?

Comment: Do you need the details of various Tensors included in the TFLite model?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal No, but I wouldn't mind. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [TensorFlow Lite docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter), you need to use a `tf.lite.Interpreter` to parse a `.tflite` model.

```
# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="converted_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

Then use the get_tensor_details method to get the list of Tensors.

```
interpreter.get_tensor_details()
```

As per the docs,

> Gets tensor details for every tensor with valid tensor details.
>   Tensors where required information about the tensor is not found are not added to the list. This includes temporary tensors without a name.
>
> Returns: A list of dictionaries containing tensor information.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a list of all used Tensorflow Lite Operations with the visualization  script.

```
wget -O tflite_visualize.py https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/visualize.py
```

Assuming your model is saved in `model.tflite` create the html file using the downloaded script.

```
python tflite_visualize.py model.tflite model_visualization.html
```

Right in the section labled **Ops**.

[image: Table of Tensorflow Lite Ops in html file]

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: If you have tensorflow installed, you can run `python -m tensorflow.lite.tools.visualize ...`